# Obtain windows 10 technical preview sdk

Tags: windows, sdk, windows-10-preview

After installing the windows 10 technical preview im facing some issues with my d3d11 application. In release mode everything works fine, but when I put it to debug mode (which means it also creates the debug device) I get an error indicating that I would have to download the D3D11 SDK Layers for Windows Technical Preview. They can be obtained by installing the Windows Technical Preview SDK. Sadly I was unable to find that SDK as a download. Do you guys know where I can find this SDK? Can it be obtained using windows update? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am going to guess they have not been released yet.  If they were you would be able to find them on Microsoft.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no SDK for the Technical Preview.

> New developer tools, SDKs, APIs, and a new universal apps model are all in the works **but the Technical Preview's focus is on OS usage, performance, and compatibility**. You can use VS 2013 and the Windows 8.1 SDK when trying it out.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/10/03/windows-10-technical-preview.aspx#10562384)

For Windows 10 Build 10041, there is an [SDK/WDK on the insider page](http://dev.windows.com/de-de/featured/hardware/windows-10-hardware-preview-tools).

Comment: Actually, right from the blog posting you linked to *"DirectX SDK Debug Layer: To obtain the Windows 10 Technical Preview version of the DirectX Debug Layer DLLs required to successfully use D3D11_CREATE_DEBUG_DEVICE or the Visual Studio 2013 Graphics Diagnostics feature, download it from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=512820). This will get integrated in a future version of the Window SDK for the RTM release of Windows 10. Be sure to install VS 2013, Windows SDK 8.1, and/or VS 2013 Remote Debugging Tools in addition to installing this patch."*

Comment: this is just a small patch with 3 Debug DLLs, but no real SDK.